# eregi_replace to preg_replace conversion

Tags: php, regex

I have upgraded my php now i am getting warning messages for eregi_replace

Can you please help me in converting following ereg expression to preg?

```
$str = eregi_replace("[[:space:]]+", " ", $str);
$text = eregi_replace('<a href=?([^ "\']*)>([^<]*)</a>', '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>', $text);
$text = eregi_replace('<a href=(\')?([^ "\']*)(\')>([^<]*)</a>', '<a href="\\2">\\4</a>', $text);
$text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',  '\\1<a href="http://\\2" target="_blank">\\2</a>', $text);
$text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})', '<a href="mailto:\\1" target="_blank">\\1</a>', $text);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion is pretty straight forward. They have a list / explanation of diffrerences [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php)

The biggest (only, maybe) change you are going to see is the addition of delimiters to the pattern strings.

Comment: i did that but I am getting error Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '?' 

#([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)#i

Comment: @jason4, you are using # as your delimiters - and also in your pattern. Pick another delimiter or escape `\#` the hash mark inside the pattern.